# Can't install Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Need a little help here to pass the grunt instalation

```
C:\Users\danie>npm install -g grunt-cli 
npm ERR! Windows_NT
  10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:878:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 8080 }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\danie\npm-debug.log
```

----   Next the npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'grunt-cli' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.12
3 info using node@v5.3.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData grunt-cli
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData grunt-cli
9 silly mapToRegistry name grunt-cli
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry http://localhost:8080/
12 silly mapToRegistry uri http://localhost:8080/grunt-cli
13 verbose request uri http://localhost:8080/grunt-cli
14 verbose request no auth needed
15 info attempt registry request try #1 at 1:08:34 AM
16 verbose request id 2b32ed7ffa936c5b
17 http request GET http://localhost:8080/grunt-cli
18 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
19 info attempt registry request try #2 at 1:08:46 AM
20 http request GET http://localhost:8080/grunt-cli
21 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
22 info attempt registry request try #3 at 1:09:47 AM
23 http request GET http://localhost:8080/grunt-cli
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:878:20)
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for grunt-cli { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080]
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'connect',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   address: '127.0.0.1',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 8080 }
25 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
27 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
29 silly install printInstalled
30 verbose stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
30 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
30 verbose stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:878:20)
30 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
31 verbose cwd C:\Users\danie
32 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
33 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
34 error node v5.3.0
35 error npm  v3.3.12
36 error code ECONNREFUSED
37 error errno ECONNREFUSED
38 error syscall connect
39 error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
39 error     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
39 error     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:878:20)
39 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
39 error  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080]
39 error   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
39 error   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
39 error   syscall: 'connect',
39 error   address: '127.0.0.1',
39 error   port: 8080 }
40 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
40 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I cleaned up your formatting. It's much easier to get help here if you format your question correctly. For text such as error logs, that means using the format as code feature (the button that looks like `{ }` in the editor).

Comment: Thank you, now is much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a connection problem.  Are you behind a proxy or something?

EDIT: Or maybe pointed at a local host npm repo or proxy? (On port 8080)

Ok, without knowing more about your system it's hard to give a non-exploratory answer, but I'll do my best to flesh it out as more of a recommendation.

It looks like your npm client is attempting to hit localhost:8080 to pull the module rather than the correct internet endpoint.  If you've not configured a local NPM repository or anything like that, run `npm config list` to see if there's anything set in there that is causing things to hit that endpoint (e.g. a configuration value).  You should also check your npmrc file, your package.json, and  your environmental variables to see if there are settings in there that are affecting things; it looks like npm is expecting a proxy.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: No, I'm not behind a proxy...  and webstorm is the only thing that could use that port right now but I can't figure it out how is this related. If it is at all.

Comment: @EdCottrell I understand but a comment could be an answer, all nice.

Comment: I decided to delete manually all the folders listened here: npm config list,  and also uninstall node, then reinstall it and the problem was fixed just like that, still I know this is not an answer, I guess the subject should still be open... but it worked! Thanks for your help Paul!

Comment: Well, the answer then is that one of those locations had the proxy set to localhost:8080.  we'll never know which since you deleted them all.

Comment: Yeap, but without your help I wouldn't do what I did, thanks!

Comment: in my case i followed thew link above and used [ npm config edit ] which opened a file inside that file i removed three lines about proxy https and similar stuff , then everything worked fine, :)